# How to create User and User Profile in a single Django Admin form

Tags: django, django-admin

I am struggling to figure out how to save User Profile for a new user created within Django Admin.

I have a custom User model and a simple user Profile with OneToOneField:

```py
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('staff'), default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=True)
    ...
```

```py
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=80, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=80, blank=False)
    ...
```

I have the following user creation form:

```py
class UserAdminCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(label="Password", widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(
        label="Password confirmation", widget=forms.PasswordInput
    )
    first_name = forms.CharField(label="First name")
    last_name = forms.CharField(label="Last name")

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("email",)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserAdminCreationForm, self).save(commit=False) 
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

My admin Add user form is rendered correctly and includes fields from both User and Profile models. After saving the form, a new user and a new profile are created in the database. However, the first_name and last_name fields in profile table are empty.

What I need to do to ensure that profile is saved together with the new user?

**UPDATE**

Overwriting the save method and ignoring the commit parameter worked for me:

```py
    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserAdminCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        user.save()
        profile, created = Profile.objects.update_or_create(user=user)
        profile.first_name = self.cleaned_data["first_name"]
        profile.last_name = self.cleaned_data["last_name"]
        profile.save()
        return user
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than making a custom form you can edit both models in one admin change form by using an [inline](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects).

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from .models import Profile

class ProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Profile
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'Profile'
    fk_name = 'user'

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = (ProfileInline, )

    def get_inline_instances(self, request, obj=None):
        if not obj:
            return list()
        return super().get_inline_instances(request, obj)


admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)
```

Since you're already defining your own custom user model, I would recommend doing away with the profile model entirely. It's just going to cause excess queries retrieving profile fields from the user instances.

**UDPATE** if you want to continue using your form:

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super(UserAdminCreationForm, self).save(commit=False) 
    user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
    if commit:
        user.save()
    Profile.objects.update_or_create(
        user=user,
        defaults={
            'first_name': self.cleaned_data['first_name'],
            'last_name': self.cleaned_data['last_name'],
        }
    )
    profile.first_name = self.cleaned_data["first_name"]
    profile.save()
    return user
```

Comment: Thanks for a prompt response bdoubleu. I need to use a custom user model, because I need users to login with an email rather than username. The current Profile model is very simple, but I will need to add additional fields. Technically, I could add all additional fields to the User model, but I understand that it is the recommend approach is to keep the User model light (i.e. only fields needed for authentication) and create a separate module for user profile info.   Is there a way to achieve what I need with two models?

Comment: Yes... you can accomplish it with what I posted above... I also made an edit with an example keeping your form. The sentences below are a suggestion. Not sure where it says to keep User models light but you're going to cause unnecessary queries with two models.

Comment: Thanks again. Unfortunately this won't work if the save method is called with commit=False, which is what is happening in my case. If the user object is not saved, it fails with  **save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'user'**.

Comment: @bdoubleu what does get_inline_instances purpose?

Comment: @Egi here it is in [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_inline_instances).